# Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL

Tags: php

I have been trying for days on how to figure this issue out. Whenever I run the code, I get this response "Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL in the console.

When I look at the network table it says "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68" I have tried lots of solutions online, yet still same issue.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

/*Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
 *   return $request->user();
 *  })->middleware('auth:api');
 */

//Cors
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE ');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, x-xsrf-token, x-csrf-token, Accept');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'cors',], function(){

    # Handling customers issues...
    Route::get('/customers', 'CountryController@index');



});





<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/agents/'

    ];
}
```

Comment: Without the code, we can't really help you.. Provide code and the line number it gets exception so we can check it out.

Comment: @Devian the code is in the image attached. That is the VerifyCsrfToken.php and Api.php. Thanks

Comment: Don't paste a screenshot. Post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: There's an error on line 69 . which means the exception is occurred on the Base verifier file. Beside that try removing the last comma from lone 15

Comment: @Devian, i just removed the last comma but still the same error

Comment: @yivi, that is the posted code. i have done lot research on it but not very helpful